# Creating instance of derived class without knowing the right derived class

Tags: python, oop

I have a base class of Event. There are multiple derived classes such as:
NetworkEvent, IOEvent and more.
Each event have a value representing the specific event type so possibly:

```
11 -> NetworkEvent (TCP send)
12 -> NetworkEvent (TCP receive)
14 -> IOEvent      (File Open)
```

Given an event that contains type, and additional parameters connected to the type, I want to return an instance of the appropriate class.

So for instance:

```
{"type": 11, "member1":"192.168.1.1", "member2":80}
```

Would return NetworkEvent instance with IP address 192.168.1.1:80

```
{"type": 14, "member1":"C:\temp\file.txt", "member2":"DOMAIN\user"}
```

Would return IOEvent for the file "C:\temp\file.txt" with the user DOMAIN\user (parsed according to the type id)

What is the correct way of doing so in python?
I'd assume that the logic for understanding the types (11, 12, etc) should be in Event class, is that correct?

I haven't tried anything specific since this is mainly about design correctness.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a factory function which accepts a dictionary as an argument - this could check the "type" value for the given dictionary then construct and return an instance of the respective Event subclass.

Comment: Hey, I thought this is the way to go as well, but I've seen several comments saying that the base class should not know of the derived classes. Maybe this is one of the instances in which we can 'break the rules' a bit. I thought about having the factory class as a @classmethod --> is that reasonable?

Comment: The factory function doesn't necessarily need to be a member of the base class - it could be in it's own class or not in a class at all